# importing Tensorflow with numpy.__version__ == 1.24.* gives AttributeError. How to fix it?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, python-3.8

I just updated my numpy from 1.19 to 1.24. But that seems to cause an error while importing tensorflow.

`import tensorflow as tf` produces the following `AttributeError`. Below is the traceback of the error.
i am using python 3.8, tensorflow 2.6.0 and numpy 1.24 (updated from 1.19). When I had numpy 1.19, code worked perfectly. But updating numpy to 1.24 seems to cause this error.
Any idea and/or fix of this conflict.

```
import tensorflow as tf

Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[7], line 1
    import tensorflow as tf

  File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/profiler/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py:41
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util

  File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/profiler/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py:46
    from tensorflow.python import data

  File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/profiler/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/__init__.py:25
    from tensorflow.python.data import experimental

  File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/profiler/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/experimental/__init__.py:97
    from tensorflow.python.data.experimental import service

  File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/profiler/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/experimental/service/__init__.py:353
    from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops.data_service_ops import distribute

  File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/profiler/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/experimental/ops/data_service_ops.py:26
    from tensorflow.python.data.experimental.ops import compression_ops

  File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/profiler/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/experimental/ops/compression_ops.py:20
    from tensorflow.python.data.util import structure

  File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/profiler/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/util/structure.py:26
    from tensorflow.python.data.util import nest

  File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/profiler/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/util/nest.py:40
    from tensorflow.python.framework import sparse_tensor as _sparse_tensor

  File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/profiler/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/sparse_tensor.py:28
    from tensorflow.python.framework import constant_op

  File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/profiler/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py:29
    from tensorflow.python.eager import execute

  File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/profiler/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py:27
    from tensorflow.python.framework import dtypes

  File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/profiler/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:585
    np.object,

  File ~/opt/anaconda3/envs/profiler/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py:305 in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(__former_attrs__[attr])

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'object'.
`np.object` was a deprecated alias for the builtin `object`. To avoid this error in existing code, use `object` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. 
The aliases was originally deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance see the original release note at:
    https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading tensorflow to 2.13 seems to have mitigated the issue.